# Notifier provider not holding value

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to save an data class to a firestore db but I have one data field that will hold it's value.

I have tried to set a notifier provider with the text value but it won't work. Here is the code:

```
ref.read(eventsNotifierProvider.notifier).updateEventDescription(eventDescriptionController.text);
```

the controller has text in it and when I pass it to the update function the value is still there. The update works without errors but the notifier provider still does not have the text. I have other update functions for the same class and they all work.

Here is the update function code:

```
  void updateEventDescription(String? newEventDescription) {
    state.copyWith(eventDescription: newEventDescription);
  }
```

In the Save function where I save the data to the db, everything works but even if I hardcode a value for the description, it won't take the value.

```
companyId:
""
eventDate:
DateTime (2023-10-29 13:30:51.802029)
eventDescription:
""
eventDuration:
""
eventName:
"kkkk"
eventStartTime:
DateTime (2023-10-29 13:30:00.000)
id:
null
userId:
""
hashCode:
988024586
runtime type:
T
```

Here is the code for the notifier provider:

```
class Events {
  String? id;
  String? eventName;
  DateTime? eventStartTime;
  String? eventDuration;
  DateTime? eventDate;
  String? eventDescription;
  String? userId;
  String? companyId;

  Events({
    this.id,
    this.eventName,
    this.eventStartTime,
    this.eventDuration,
    this.eventDate,
    this.eventDescription,
    this.userId,
    this.companyId,
  });

  // Reading data from firebase and converting it into Event type
  factory Events.fromJson(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    Map data = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
    return Events(
      id: doc.id,
      eventName: data['eventName'],
      eventStartTime: (data['eventStartTime'] as Timestamp).toDate(),
      eventDuration: data['eventDuration'],
      eventDate: (data['eventDate'] as Timestamp).toDate(),
      eventDescription: data['eventDescription'],
      userId: data['userId'],
      companyId: data['companyId'],
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'eventName': eventName,
      'eventStartTime': eventStartTime,
      'eventDuration': eventDuration,
      'eventDate': eventDate,
      'eventDescription': eventDescription,
      'agentId': userId,
      'agencyId': companyId,
    };
  }

  Events copyWith({
    String? eventName,
    DateTime? eventStartTime,
    String? eventDuration,
    DateTime? eventDate,
    String? eventDescription,
    String? userId,
    String? companyId,
  }) {
    return Events(
      eventName: eventName ?? this.eventName,
      eventStartTime: eventStartTime ?? this.eventStartTime,
      eventDuration: eventDuration ?? this.eventDuration,
      eventDate: eventDate ?? this.eventDate,
      eventDescription: eventDescription ?? this.eventDescription,
      userId: userId ?? this.userId,
      companyId: companyId ?? this.companyId,
    );
  }
}

class EventsNotifier extends Notifier<Events> {
  final firestoreService = FirestoreService();
  FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  final eventRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(('events'));
  EventsNotifier();

  @override
  Events build() {
    return Events(
      // Return the initial state
      eventName: '',
      eventStartTime: DateTime.now(),
      eventDuration: '',
      eventDate: DateTime.now(),
      eventDescription: '',
      userId: '',
      companyId: '',
    );
  }

  String? eventName;
  DateTime? eventStartTime;
  String? eventDuration;
  DateTime? eventDate;
  String? eventDescription;
  String? userId;
  String? companyId;

  void updateEventname(String? newEventName) {
    state = state.copyWith(eventName: newEventName);
  }

  void updateeventStartTime(DateTime? newEventStartTime) {
    state = state.copyWith(eventStartTime: newEventStartTime);
  }

  void updateEventDuration(String? newEventDuration) {
    state = state.copyWith(eventDuration: newEventDuration);
  }

  void updateEventDate(DateTime? newEventDate) {
    state.copyWith(eventDate: newEventDate);
  }

  void updateEventDescription(String? newEventDescription) {
    state.copyWith(eventDescription: newEventDescription);
  }

  // pass in a map and get an object back
  EventsNotifier.fromFirestore(Map<String, dynamic> firestore)
      : eventName = firestore['eventName'],
        eventStartTime = firestore['eventStartTime'].toDate(),
        eventDuration = firestore['eventDuration'],
        eventDate = firestore['eventDate'].toDate(),
        eventDescription = firestore['eventDescription'],
        userId = firestore['agentId'],
        companyId = firestore['agencyId'];

  saveEvent(Events events, String? eventDesc, [String? eventId]) {
    var newEvent = Events(
        eventName: events.eventName,
        eventStartTime: events.eventStartTime,
        eventDuration: events.eventDuration,
        eventDate: events.eventDate,
        eventDescription: "rrrrr", //events.eventDescription, <<< PROBLEM HERE
        companyId: ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider).companyId,
        userId: ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider).currentUserId);

    if (eventId != null && eventId != '') {
      firestoreService.saveEvent(
          newEvent, ref, eventId); // Update existing event
      ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider.notifier).updatenewEvent(false);
    } else {
      firestoreService.saveEvent(newEvent, ref); // Create new event
    }
  }

  deleteEvent(String? eventId) {
    firestoreService.deleteEvent(eventId, ref);
  }
}
```

Here is where I try to update the notifier provider:

```
try {
                      ref
                          .read(globalsNotifierProvider.notifier)
                          .updatenewEvent(true);
                      if (currentEventId != null && currentEventId != '') {
                        ref.read(eventsNotifierProvider.notifier).saveEvent(
                            ref.read(eventsNotifierProvider), currentEventId);
                      } else {
                        ref
                            .read(eventsNotifierProvider.notifier)
                            .updateEventDescription(
                                eventDescriptionController.text);

                        ref.read(eventsNotifierProvider.notifier).saveEvent(
                            ref.read(eventsNotifierProvider),
                            eventDescriptionController
                                .text); // Create new event
                      }

                      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => AppointmentCalendarScreen()));

                      setState(() {
                        showSpinner = false;
                      });
                    }
```

Why is this happening and how do I fix it?
Thanks

UPDATE:

```
final eventsNotifierProvider = NotifierProvider<EventsNotifier, Events>(() {
  return EventsNotifier();
});
```

Comment: Where do you define your provider?  Is it keepalive or autodispose?

Comment: No idea. I have never heard of those options.

Comment: Show the definition of "eventsNotifierProvider".

Comment: It is up in the original post. It is the 3rd set of code.

Comment: No, it's not.  I've carefully searched for "eventsNotifierProvider" and never see it defined, just used.

Comment: Sorry, I added it to the very bottom of the original post. Thanks

Comment: Ahh, didn't notice that updateEventDescription and updateEventDate methods do not have the proper state = state.copyWith.  Please make sure they all update the identity of state, or add notifyListeners() to those methods.

Comment: Yes, I missed that too. Thanks for catching that for me.